# How do I make sure that the labels of a echarts4r radar chart are completely visible on any screen? Works with bs4Dash::box but not with bslib::card

Tags: r, shiny, echarts4r

I am creating a radar chart via echarts4r package in a shiny app. On small screens, the labels of the radar chart cut off. How do I make sure that the labels are completely visible on any screen? I understand that any solution for this would mean that the radar chart size decreases to accommodate the labels.

#### Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    echarts4rOutput("radar_chart")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$radar_chart <- renderEcharts4r({
    df <- data.frame(
      x = c("Loooong", "Verrrrry long", "Extreeeeeeeeemely long", "Short", "Min"),
      y = runif(5, 1, 5),
      z = runif(5, 3, 7)
    )
    
    df |>
      e_charts(x) |>
      e_radar(y, max = 7) |>
      e_radar(z) |>
      e_tooltip(trigger = "item") |>
      e_radar_opts(
        axisName = list(
          color = "black",
          fontFamily = "Libre Franklin",
          fontSize = 18
        ))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### `bs4Dash` example (radar chart labels are visible on any screen size)

In this example of bs4Dash, when the radar chart is wrapped in `box`, the size is adjusted:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(echarts4r)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)


df = data.frame(name=c('A','B','C'),
                color = c('blue','white','green'),
                atr1 = c(34,45,32),
                atr2 = c(56,32,21),
                atr3 = c(23,45,21))

# UI

ui = dashboardPage(
  title = "Example radar plot",
  header = dashboardHeader(
    title = dashboardBrand(
      title = "radarchart test",
      color = "primary"
    )),
  
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    selectizeInput('sel1','name',choices = NULL),
    selectizeInput('sel2','color',choices = NULL)
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    box(echarts4rOutput("radar"))
  )
)

# SERVER

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Filter update
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'sel1', choices = sort(unique(df$name)),selected = "A" ,server = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$sel1, {
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "sel2", label="color",
                      choices = df[df$name==input$sel1,]$color)
  })
  
  #Table creation to use in radarplot
  dataradar = reactive({
    dataradar = df[df$name==input$sel1 & df$color == input$sel2, c('atr1','atr2','atr3')]
    dataradar = data.table(dataradar)
    dataradar = melt(dataradar, measure.vars = c(names(dataradar))) 
  })
  
  
  #radar plot
  output$radar <- renderEcharts4r({
    if(!nrow(dataradar()))
      return()
    
    dataradar() %>%
      e_charts(variable)  %>%
      e_radar(value) |> 
      e_radar_opts(
        axisName = list(
          color = "black",
          fontFamily = "Libre Franklin",
          fontSize = 18
        ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I tried using `bslib::card` (in place of `box` in the original example code), but that does not adjust the size of radar chart on small screen size as `box` did. Any ideas how can I mimic the same behaviour?